# SQLite & ODBC - Concatenation

Tags: sqlite, odbc

I am using SQLite version 3.33 with [this](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/sqliteodbc.exe) ODBC Driver. How do I concatenate strings with SQL statements?
I have tried

```
select 'sun' || 'flower';
```

That expression works with SQLite Command Line Interface (CLI) but fails. I've also tried

```
select 'sun' + 'flower'; 
select concat('sun','flower');
```

These also fail; I'm aware that SQLite does not support *concat*.
I am using ADODB to evaluate the SQL statement.
How do I concatenate strings using the ODBC driver?

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
select 'sun' || 'flower';
```

has the correct syntax and it works. I investigated further following the feedback [here](https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/d75b05f146)

The problem I was having is down to APL which cannot pass the operator || to ADODB.